# Recommendations for Android programming resources

Tags: android

I am working on getting familiar with the Android SDK and I have having a hard time getting the UI side of things figured out. I am trying to create a *menu*, kind of like how apps are listed in the market place or how the contact list works. Where I would have basically a list view and treat each item in the list as a button, so I can display information based on their selection.

Does anyone have any good examples/tutorials/guides/resources I can look at to try and get a better idea of how this works?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: These kinds of survey questions don't fit the SO format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Selection/List/) is an example of a `ListActivity` showing a list and getting control when the user clicks on the list.

[Here](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) is an excerpt from one of my books showing how to make that list look more elaborate.

[Here](http://wiki.andmob.org/books) is a list of the available books on Android development (in the interests of full disclosure, I'm maintaining that list and I wrote a few of the books on it).

[Here](http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/47661) is a blog post I wrote with pointers to other resources for assistance, plus a [guide for making best use of StackOverflow](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/12/21/devs-get-thee-to-stackoverflow/) for Android questions.

There are also [articles](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/index.html), [some](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) [tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html), and other [samples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/index.html) out on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/index.html).

Comment: Hey, great links. Does the first example correspond to any specific example in one of your books?

Comment: The first example is from one of my books -- all of the book source code samples are up on various github repos of mine (http://github.com/commonsguy). That one specifically is from _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_, Version 2.0, Chapter 7 ("Using Selection Widgets"). The excerpt is, in effect, Chapter 8 of that same book.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I went ahead and got a warescription. Hopefully next time I have a question you will be skimming SO.

Answer (score 2):

The API Demos on the Android dev site are really great. There are all sorts of simple examples of what the OS is capable of. The demos should have come packaged with the SDK.

https://developer.android.com/samples/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a limitation on what you can find on the Internet regarding Android tutorials. I strongly recommend going to a bookstore or ordering off Amazon [**Beginning Android**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224193) (*which I have personally read and learned **alot** out of*)